# Match file names with prefix, few digits and a suffix regex

Tags: regular-expression, ls

How do I match file names `abc_NNN.xyz`? here is the directory content

```
[root@ tmp]# ls -ltr
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jan  3 00:42 abc_123.xyz
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jan  3 00:42 abc_234.xyz
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jan  3 00:42 abc_345.xyz
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jan  3 00:43 abc_def_123.xyz
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jan  3 00:44 abc_def_234.xyz
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jan  3 00:44 abc_def_345.xyz
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jan  3 01:57 abc_123_123.xyz
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jan  3 01:57 abc_234_234.xyz
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jan  3 01:57 abc_345_345.xyz
```

This one works for me

```
[root@ tmp]# ls -ltr abc_[0-9][0-9][0-9].xyz
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jan  3 00:42 abc_123.xyz
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jan  3 00:42 abc_234.xyz
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jan  3 00:42 abc_345.xyz
```

The problem is that in the real scenario I need to match `abc_NNNNNNNNN.xyz` so the expression is too large. I am looking for something similar to `abc_[0-9]{3}.xyz`, `abc_[0-9]+3.xyz` (obviously these doesn't work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the original simpler examples you listed, `abc_[0-9]*.xyz` will work. That obviously will match some things other than numbers, but will exclude the `def` files you've listed as the first character after the first underscore is not a digit in those cases.

For the more complicated examples, it's probably time to deploy `find` so we can actually use regular expressions:

```
$ ls
abc_123_123.xyz  abc_123.xyz  abc_234_234.xyz  abc_234.xyz  abc_345_345.xyz  abc_345.xyz  abc_def_123.xyz  abc_def_234.xyz  abc_def_345.xyz
$ find . -regex '\./abc_[0-9]+\.xyz'
./abc_345.xyz
./abc_234.xyz
./abc_123.xyz
```

That's with GNU `find`, other variants may differ slightly.

Comment: I updated the question, the directory has abc_NNN_NNN.xyz file names too, I want to match only abc_NNN.xyz

Comment: Updated to use a proper regex tool :-)

Comment: Worked for the actual use case I was aiming for too, I just had to run the find results through `sort` but other than that your solution is the closet to what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `bash`, you could also make use of its extended globbing capabilites:

```
shopt -s extglob
ls abc_+([0-9]).xyz
```

Sample uutput:

```
abc_123456.xyz
abc_123.xyz
abc_1.xyz
abc_3456.xyz
abc_345.xyz
abc_56789.xyz
abc_567.xyz
```

The `+([0-9])` expression matches one or more instances of any digit. This which will match the 'NNNN' pattern of any length.

Comment: I'm not sure about `shopt -s extglob`, how standard is that?

Comment: @e271p314 It's a shell option that's built into bash. Ksh also has a similar extended globbing option, but the syntax may be slightly different.

Comment: I confirm it worked for me, first time I hear about `shopt -s extglob`, thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [POSIX glob — how to match one-or-more [:digit:]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38063998/4397227) shell globing is not equal to regex. You are probably best of processing the `ls` output with `grep` in which case your originally mentioned `abc_[0-9]{3}.xyz` pattern would work.

You can combine the two as such:

```
[root@ tmp]# ls -ltr abc_[0-9]+.xyz | grep abc_[0-9]{3}.xyz
```

Comment: [Please don't try and parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Didn't work, with  `ls -ltr abc_[0-9]+.xyz` no files match, with `ls -ltr abc_[0-9]*.xyz` files match but when I pipe it through `grep abc_[0-9]{3}.xyz` I get no results